# MP-APS damage assists

Tags: battlefield-4

I battlelog in kits section MP-APS gadget has stat "damage assists".

[image]

How is it counted? Is it implemented at all?

Comment: I've tried using this a few times and I've never seen it activate or award me points for anything.

Comment: It useful sometimes, it stops 25mm bullets from boats and helicopters.

Comment: Not sure how the MPAPS can do this to be honest...it can only "absorb" damage. And it will protect against all tank shells, TV missiles, chopper rockets and portable launchers, but will not stop grenades or small arms-fire.

Comment: Maybe if an enemy is standing near your MPAPS, and it detonates an incoming explosive, it will cause damage to the enemy. Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

The MP-APS is compareable to the reactive armour of MBT and IFV but not bound to a single vehicle.

It will destroy any incoming explosive rockets and shells, no matther if coming from inf or vehicles.

It's only working in a 180° arc and has a cooldown.

After deploying, it needs 3 seconds to work, and after every rocket/shell it has destroyed, it needs 5 seconds cooldown.

This is used far to seldom, I guess people don't understand how it works, or are just annoyed of picking it up when moving ahead. 
For example on Shanghai, sometimes there are 4-6 tanks/lavs fighting at the same time against each other. If one team would set up 2 MP-APS they would win guaranteed! Every second enemy tankshell would be blocked by the MP-APS, the other shells could be taken by reactive armour and repairing engineers with easy.
So if you are playing in a whole tank-squad with 2-3 tanks/lav, be sure to have a guy taking the MP-APS, its awesome!
Due it's support class, if the supporter deploys a ammobox on the tank he's inside, he might reload the MP-APS while inside the tank. so it's no problem if he forgot to pick it up after leaving the one spot.

Also, it can be used to block some of these anoying 40mm granades on Metro/locker, even further it blinds enemies, at least a little bit.

Comment: This is useful description on usage tactics, but it is not answering question about assists tracking.